# After migration from Hibernate to EclipeLink getting many SQL Exceptions

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

After migration JPA project from Hibernate I'm getting many such exceptions:

```
    Aug 31, 2015 4:00:52 PM org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/var/folders/ls/0vdttqm92zq1rtcsjntc4mxw0000gn/T/gfembed8285464623855636118tmp/applications/salonea-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_LocalServicesMySQL_JTA
WARNING: 
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') REFERENCES  ()' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: ALTER TABLE provider ADD CONSTRAINT fk_provider_corporation FOREIGN KEY () REFERENCES  ()
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE provider ADD CONSTRAINT fk_provider_corporation FOREIGN KEY () REFERENCES  ()")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3214)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.priviledgedExecuteNonSelectingCall(AbstractSession.java:5008)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.TableDefinition.createForeignConstraintsOnDatabase(TableDefinition.java:891)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.tools.schemaframework.SchemaManager.createForeignConstraints(SchemaManager.java:194)
```

They seem to be related to foreign key constraints created for @OneToMany, @ManyToMany, etc association. 
There are also JUnit tests that now don't pass related to bulk deletion (DELETE FROM) of entities associated in such ManyToMany. In hibernate this test have been passing well, and in EclipseLink there is some error.

I don't know whether below errors foreign key constraints may influence this situation? 
If EclipseLink has totally different implementation and this is so hard to port app from Hibernate (code working in Hibernate can don't work in EclipseLink)

Now I see that in Hibernate there are also similar errors:

```
HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table natural_person drop foreign key FK_xebs35hpmkrexufr4i267ak1
Table "NATURAL_PERSON" not found; SQL statement:
    alter table natural_person 
        drop 
        foreign key FK_xebs35hpmkrexufr4i267ak1 [42102-173]
</event></ijLog>
ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table natural_person drop foreign key FK_xebs35hpmkrexufr4i267ak1
ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] Table "NATURAL_PERSON" not found; SQL statement:
    alter table natural_person 
        drop 
        foreign key FK_xebs35hpmkrexufr4i267ak1 [42102-173]
HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table photo_tagged_with drop foreign key FK_gcjvuf4mauiptth529s2e4gjw
HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table provider drop foreign key fk_provider_corporation
Table 'salonea.provider' doesn't exist
Table "PHOTO_TAGGED_WITH" not found; SQL statement:
    alter table photo_tagged_with 
        drop 
        foreign key FK_gcjvuf4mauiptth529s2e4gjw [42102-173]
```

Comment: This is DDL generation, not JPA runtime - the exception should be logged as a warning and proceed.  Check that your tables are created as you would expect when it is done.  If you do want to debug what is happening with that constraint, you would need to show the entity the provider table is mapped to

Comment: Why are you migrating to eclipselink? Does eclipselink have some features that are missing in hibernate?

Comment: I need glass fish, I would prefer wildlfy/hibernate, but must do front-end to the end of September and I would like to try Ozark MVC 1.0 implementation (cause I would like to use this approach rather than jsf) currently I need some sample font-end not sophisticated so early draft shouldn't be a huge problem

Comment: so you quote SQL exceptions, for EclipseLink and Hibernate yet don't provide the code that they relate to, so there is no context to the question so nobody can give any educated opinion on why you get those.